# Maintaining Sourdough Starter - Are potato flakes/water necessary?

Tags: bread, sourdough, starter, starch, sourdough-starter

I just got some sourdough starter going with the Oregon Trail, and it seems to be doing quite well. However, the guide calls for using potato flakes or potato water to feed it- having neither, I hoped for the best and used some arrowroot powder instead. I'm not sure what the purpose of the potato stuff is- is it just food? I figured it might be primarily for providing starch, in which case the arrowroot should be fine.

Comment: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/53842/adding-things-to-sourdough-starter-culture

Comment: Hi! As you already said yourself, what you have are two independent questions. Putting them into the same "thread" makes the information very hard to find - the title is necessarily too broad to indicate what the questions are about, the answers will mix solutions to two different problems, and so on. Also, it is hard to vote when a question has independent parts which would merit separate voting. It is not so good for you either - you are losing half of your potential votes. It would be very good if you could split it - delete the part about the vibration, and open a new question about it.

Comment: You're right, that makes a lot more sense.

Comment: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/1124/34529

Answer (score 1):

I feed sourdough starter with strong white bread flour mixed with water to make a sloppy dough. This is a common method in the UK and it seems to work well.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used anything other than good old bread flour or all-purpose flour. I've had a lot of success with Peter Reinhart's system of doubling the weight of your starter with equal parts flour and water. In other words, if your starter weighs 4 ounces, feed your starter with 2 ounces flour and 2 ounces water. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I've only ever used white flour and water, nothing else. I mix mine with equal weights of both to get a 100% hydration starter.

Nothing else is at all necessary.