# Is it okay to feed milk powder to sourdough starter?

Tags: substitutions, bread, yeast, sourdough, sourdough-starter

I'm still new to bread making and I was wondering if adding some milk powder when I feed my starter would have a negative impact since milk is slightly more acidic than flour.

Comment: Welcome to SA!  Why would you want to feed it milk powder?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Also, it sounds like you mean feeding the bulk starter, but some sourdough approaches take some out to use, feed that, then use it to make bread. Feeding milk powder at that point would mean the parent starter didn't stay milky. I'm not saying that's common but it would avoid risking your main starter.

Comment: I think all the answers to this question applies here as well - https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/53842/adding-sugar-and-honey-to-sourdough-culture

Answer (score 1):

I would never hazard the main starter but would try adding milk to the levain fully used for the current loaf only to see if it adds more tang!